# ToolBox не дает установить обновление Pycharm

Tags: python, установка, jetbrains

Собирался установить обновление на Pycharm, но Toolbox не дает этого сделать и выдает такое сообщение, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перезагрузить/Переустановить пробовали?

Comment: обновил тулбокс не помогло

Comment: запусти toolbox от имени администратора. Мне помогло